# Matlab Loading modular displays into GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am working on building a modular testing module for my robotics team.  So far, the module looks like this:

[image: Testing module]

Is it possible to design displays independently from this test module and then to load them into the lower portion of the GUI screen?

Comment: Are you designing this with GUIDE or programmatically?

Comment: Right now with GUIDE, but since I've only started, I am open to either approach.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly possible to design GUI "module" independently. You may have to keep good track of the graphic object handles but that goes for any GUI anyway.

I'll propose an example showing one way to do it (there are several other ways though). This way would require to design your GUI programmatically (you could adjust it to GUIDE designed GUI but it would require a lot of fiddling around and I wouldn't recommend it).

The basic approach is to have functions which lay out the "module" (create and position all the `uicontrol`, `axes` etc...) in a **generic container** instead of a `figure`. When you need to load a module, you can just create a container (I use `uipanel` in the example), and load the module in this container. When you want to change the active module, you can simply *delete* the container (Matlab will delete all the children objects) then load a new module in a fresh container. Alternatively you could just load all the modules, hide them all (set `'visible','off'` on all the container, then only make visible the current module in use.

In the example, the 3 different functions which define a module are in the same file than the main function, but they could be each in separate file. (I personally use an application which has close to 40 modules so you can guess it is more manageable to have them in different files).

Here's how it look like, and the code just follow:
[image: Modular GUI]

Code for `Modular_GUI_sample.m`:
(The most interesting section for you is in the function `Module_Selection_callback`)

```
function h = Modular_GUI_sample

%// The main figure
h.figMain = figure('Name','Testing Module',...
    'Menubar','none','Toolbar','none',...
    'NumberTitle','off','Units','Normalized' ) ;

%// The Module Selection panel
h.ms = Create_Module_Selection_UI(h.figMain) ;

%// save the ui object handles structure
guidata( h.figMain , h )


function Module_Selection_callback(hobj, ~)
selectedModuleName = get( get( hobj , 'SelectedObject' ), 'String') ;

%// retrieve the global handle structure
h = guidata( hobj ) ;
%// Delete old module if present
if isfield(h,'hmod')
    if ishandle(h.hmod.pnl) ;
        delete(h.hmod.pnl) ;    % delete the panel and children object
        h.hmod = [] ;           % clear the structure
    end
end
%// The panel which will contain the selected module
spc = 0.05 ; % spacing value for margins
h.hmod.pnl = uipanel('Units','Normalized','Position',[spc spc (1-2*spc) (0.7-2*spc)],'BackgroundColor','w') ;

%// load new module
switch selectedModuleName
    case 'Locomotion'
        hmod = Load_Module_Locomotion(h.hmod.pnl) ;
    case 'Vision'
        hmod = Load_Module_Vision(h.hmod.pnl) ;
    case 'Localization'
        hmod = Load_Module_Localization(h.hmod.pnl) ;
end
%// save the ui object handles structure
h.mod = hmod ;
guidata( h.figMain , h )


function hmod = Load_Module_Locomotion(parent)
%// main container panel
hmod.pnl = parent ;
spc = 0.05 ;
hmod.list = uicontrol('Parent',parent,'Style','listbox','Units','Normalized','Position',[spc spc (1-2*spc) (1-2*spc)]) ;
set(hmod.list,'String',{'List Item 1','List Item 2','List Item 3'},'Value',1 ) ;


function hmod = Load_Module_Vision(parent)
%// main container panel
hmod.pnl = parent ;
hmod.ax1 = subplot(2,2,1,'Parent',parent) ;
hmod.ax1 = subplot(2,2,3,'Parent',parent) ;
hmod.ax1 = subplot(2,2,[2 4],'Parent',parent) ;


function hmod = Load_Module_Localization(parent)
%// main container panel
hmod.pnl = parent ;
spc = 0.05 ;
hmod.list = uicontrol('Parent',parent,'Style','pushbutton','String','A big push button','Units','Normalized','Position',[spc spc (1-2*spc) (1-2*spc)]) ;


function ms = Create_Module_Selection_UI(parent)
%// prepare position calculation helper
spc = 0.05 ; %// spacing value for margins
nButtons = 3 ;
btnH = (1-(nButtons+1)*spc)/nButtons ;
radioPos = @(k) [spc (1-(k*(spc+btnH))) (1-2*spc) btnH ] ;

%// The main "Module Selection" panel (actually a "uibuttongroup" object)
ms.pnl = uibuttongroup('Parent',parent,'Position',[spc 0.7 (1-2*spc) 0.3-spc],'BackgroundColor','w') ;

%// prepare properties which will be common for this group of uicontrols
radioProps = {'Parent',ms.pnl , 'Style','radiobutton' , 'Units','Normalized' } ;
%// Create three radio buttons in the button group.
k=0;
k=k+1 ; ms.radLocomotion    = uicontrol( radioProps{:} , 'Position',radioPos(k) , 'String','Locomotion' ) ;
k=k+1 ; ms.radVision        = uicontrol( radioProps{:} , 'Position',radioPos(k) , 'String','Vision' ) ;
k=k+1 ; ms.radLocalization  = uicontrol( radioProps{:} , 'Position',radioPos(k) , 'String','Localization' ) ;

%// Initialize some button group properties.
set(ms.pnl,'SelectionChangeFcn',@Module_Selection_callback);
set(ms.pnl,'SelectedObject',[]);  % No selection
```

---

If you need to programmatically design extensive GUI, I encourage you to consider using the [GUI Layout Toolbox](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47982-gui-layout-toolbox) from the file exchange. It is quite robust, and it makes designing GUI in Matlab a breeze compared to having to position (and resize) all your controls programmatically (you wouldn't need to do all the position calculation that I have in the example for example).